# Program Creality v2.2 board to use HEATER1 transistor for HEATER0

Tags: marlin, hotend, creality-cr-10, th3d

My CR10-S5 with Creality v2.2 mainboard recently suffered from the hotend heater transistor (MOSFET) failing short. After taking a look at the board, I tried to be clever and use the `HEATER1` output instead for my hotend. However, after swapping pins in `pins_RAMPS.h`, there is no response to turning on the heater. I have confirmed zero volts on the board output with a multimeter, so it shouldn't be a failed heater cartridge.

Are there any other lines of code I should be changing to get this to work? I am using TH3D Unified 2 firmware with BLTouch enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem, apparently these v2.2, v2.2x boards have the `HEATER1` MOSFET controlled by pin 7, not pin 9 as in default `pins_RAMPS.h`. After setting `HEATER0` to use pin 7 everything works as expected.